# python How to sum all the numbers in a treeview column

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to sum all the numbers of the "Total Sum" Column of Treeview:

[image: screenshot]

The code is:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

def update():
    listBox.insert('','end',value=('APL', t1.get(),t2.get(),t3.get()))

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')

e8 = tk.Label(root,text="APL").grid(row=1,column=0)
t1 = tk.Entry(root)
t1.grid(row=1,column=1)
t2 = tk.Entry(root)
t2.grid(row=1,column=2)
t3 = tk.Entry(root)
t3.grid(row=1,column=3)

cols = ('name', 'No1', 'No2', 'total sum')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=cols, show='headings')

for col in cols:
    listBox.heading(col, text=col)
    listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    listBox.place(x=10, y=300)

b = tk.Button(root,text='Update Listbox',command=update)
b.grid(row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: sum of no1 and no2 in your image is supposed to be 10+10, how is that 100?Did you mean product and why are you inserting a number onto `t3` let the system do it for you?

Comment: i'm just manually entered. i need 100's total.

Comment: Do you want it to be automatically done?

Comment: automatically and button based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method to do what you want,

Start of by making a button and a function to it:

```
b1 = tk.Button(root,text='Add Listbox',command=add)
b1.grid(row=4)
```

then the `add()` can be something like:

```
def add():
    total = 0.0

    for child in listBox.get_children():
        total += float(listBox.item(child, 'values')[3])
    
    lbl = Label(root,text=total,font=('helvetica',18))
    lbl.grid(row=5)
```

This will print the total of the item in the final column.

**Tip:**

You can insert the sum of entry box automatically onto the third entry box.

```
def added():
    # Sets the sum of values of e1 and e2 as val of e3
    try :
        sum_tk.set((int(t1.get().replace(' ', '')) + int(t2.get().replace(' ', ''))))
    except :
        pass
    
    root.after(1, added) # reschedule the event
    return
```

Then you should define something like and change the code to below.

```
sum_tk = tk.StringVar()
t3 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=sum_tk)
t3.grid(row=1,column=3)
```

and towards the end of the code, add

```
root.after(1,added)
```

This will call the function when the code begins.

[Above extra answer taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63739839/python-i-want-two-entry-widgets-sum-without-using-button)

If you dont want buttons, then remove the button and its function and just change your `update()` as below.

```
def update():
    if t1.get() == '' or t2.get() == '' or t3.get() == '':
        pass
    else:
        listBox.insert('','end',value=('APL', t1.get(),t2.get(),t3.get()))
    total = 0.0
    try:
        for child in listBox.get_children():
            total += float(listBox.item(child, 'values')[3])
    except:
        pass
    print(total)
    lbl = Label(root,text=total,font=('helvetica',21))
    lbl.grid(row=5)

    t1.delete(0,'end')
    t2.delete(0,'end')
    t3.delete(0,'end')
```

Hope this helped, do let me know if any doubts or errors.

Cheers

Comment: i need total in tkinter gui

Comment: Take a look at list of videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQSEXcf6s2I&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV). This is how i learned.

Comment: anyway, would appreciate if you could mark this as the correct answer

Comment: Ive updated my answer, if you want the entire code do let me know

Comment: Updated the answer, again

Comment: total += float(listBox.item(child, 'values')[3])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: Updated again, take a look